# Which columns should I add to a PRIMARY KEY

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

I want to create a table and avoid duplicated entries, by creating a PRIMARY KEY. The problem is I don't know which columns I should add to this KEY. Consider the next table:

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `id_c` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `lang` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(80) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `franchise` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `id_c` (`id_c`),
  KEY `lang` (`lang`),
  KEY `franchise` (`franchise`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**id_c**: Id of customer. It can be an enterprise. Suppose *McDonald's*
**lang**: Contact language.
**boss**: Boss' name
**franchise**: If not zero, it is a franchise. McDonald's in Rome, Paris, London...
As you can see, each **ENTERPRISE** can have different **central** "shops" in each country (*contact language*), but also different ***franchises*** in each city (where boss' name would be different).
I want to be able to INSERT new rows where the **id_c**, **lang** can be not-distinct (many franchises in same country). But **name** has to be distinct only if (**id_c,lang**) is the same (for other id_c,lang combination... name could be the same). And franchise can be the same too only if it has not been assigned in the same (id_c,lang) pair. 
I was thinking about a PRIMARY KEY (`lang`,`name`), but it might not be the best way. Is this table structure just too complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a multiple column `UNIQUE` constraint,

```
CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (id_c,lang, name)
```

or set them as the primary key,

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` 
(
  `id_c` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `lang` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(80) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `franchise` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `id_c` (`id_c`),
  KEY `lang` (`lang`),
  KEY `franchise` (`franchise`),
  CONSTRAINT tb_PK PRIMARY KEY (id_c,lang, name)    --- <<== compound PK
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Thank you. But I still have two questions: why UNIQUE and not PRIMARY? A UNIQUE constraint is the same as a UNIQUE INDEX, isn't it? Thanks!

Comment: because I thought you want to have another PK so that's why I used `UNIQUE` rather than `PK`. anyway, both creates automatic index.

Answer (score 1):

If i get your question right...u are asking which columns to choose...and not HOW to do it?Correct?

So i'd guess that franchise number is not a boolean(YES/NO) thing but holds a number unique for each shop?...each country? If thats the case then go with id_c and franchise.
If not you can choose all 4 of them to be the key...but i think thats not a good practise.In that case i'd say that you should add one more column(trueID for example - autoincrement integer) and use this one as your primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Just give Id as primary key. Because using Id_c you can get other column values. As you see the best advice is to create your Primary id should be in first column.

Comment: Thanks... but, if only `id_c` is a PK, then I could duplicate entries. For example, I could have the same franchise twice for the same (id_c, lang, name) pair.